# sql conditional where clause

Tags: sql

I have two records on my table:

**Table:**

```
ID StartDate   EndDate
1  2013-01-01  2016-01-01 
2  2016-02-01  NULL
```

My query:

```
@DatePeriodFrom = 2016-01-01
@DatePeriodTo = 2016-01-01

select *
from tableabove ta
where (ta.StartDate >= @DatePeriodFrom and ta.EndDate >= @DatePeriodTo)
```

My problem here is that it will return no results. If I replace `and` with `or`, it will return both rows. I am thinking of using `ISNULL` but no luck for me.

**EDIT**

What I want is to return the row based from the given Start date and end date regardless if the row has null end date.

On the example above, the 1st row should be returned.

On this example, the 2nd row should be returned:

```
@DatePeriodFrom = 2016-02-01
@DatePeriodTo = 2016-02-01
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if you need to find all intersections of periods:

```
where ta.StartDate <= @DatePeriodTo
    and (ta.endDate IS NULL or ta.endDate >= @DatePeriodFrom)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from tableabove ta
where ta.StartDate <= @DatePeriodFrom and (ta.endDate is NULL or ta.EndDate >= @DatePeriodTo)
```

Output: [Table values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPcm0.png)

[image: Output]

[image]

Comment: Wait, I tried changing the dates. My start date and end date is 2016-02-01 and when I ran the query, it returned both rows. It should only return the 2nd row.

Comment: Yes it will return both rows as per the query, So you do not want the second row right ?. You do not want it to match with NULL ?

Comment: it should only return the 2nd row since my startdate and enddate  is 2016-02-01 and the 2nd row has start date of 2016-02.

Comment: Hi, I did it on my local. And the output I am getting is only second row.

Comment: Can you please check again while comparing dates

Comment: See edited answer. I pasted the output and table values

Comment: Hi. Can you try this one last? Start and end date is 2016-01-01. It should return no rows, right?

Comment: It will return first row and it is returning the same

Comment: Why it will not return any rows ?

Comment: I am thinking if it should be within the range of the two dates.

Comment: Yes it is within the range only, as 2016-01-01>=2016-01-01

Comment: If you want it lesser remove the =

Comment: But my period from is 2013? and in my 1st row the start date is 2016.

Comment: Your start date is 2013 and you are entering start date as 2016. So it will work. Any date lesser than 2013 will not work.

Answer (score 1):

first of all i think you ment to use  @DatePeriodTo <= ta.EndDate, not '>='.

assuming startdate cannot be null, condition should be:

```
where ta.StartDate >= @DatePeriodFrom
and (ta.EndDate is null or ta.EndDate <= @DatePeriodTo)
```

One more concern even if not applicable to this case... Check if column type contains only date or date and time... 31.12.2010 10:00PM > '31.12.2010'

Comment: I think you mean `ta.StartDate <= @DatePeriodFrom`?

Comment: This is what I wrote in my answer

Comment: It depends what you want. I wrote a condition for records that start and ends within my period. If you want records that are alive your whole period, it is different. And if you want records that are just partialy alive during period, another codition must be written. Tell me what is your case.

Comment: How can this work : where ta.StartDate >= @DatePeriodFrom. Great thing is you got an upvote for your solution

Comment: it just says you want records that started at least at 'start of the period'. Where is the problem?

Comment: So, is should be where ta.StartDate <= @DatePeriodFrom. Think again.

Comment: I do not really think that it is so complicated. It just depends on what do you want. I want record start be after my period. You want it to be before.

Answer (score 1):

Once again:

Case A) 
I want the records that are 'alive' during whole period:

```
where ta.StartDate <= @DatePeriodFrom
and (ta.EndDate is null or ta.EndDate >= @DatePeriodTo)
```

Case B)
I want the records that were created and ended during the period

```
where ta.StartDate >= @DatePeriodFrom
and (ta.EndDate <= @DatePeriodTo)
```

Case C)
I want the records that were just alive during my period:

```
where ta.StartDate <= @DatePeriodTo 
and (ta.EndDate is null or ta.EndDate >= @DatePeriodFrom)
```